# How to configure Visual Studio (2010) to open aspx pages on code behind by default on double click?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, configuration, default, code-behind

The question says it all... its pretty simple, and it can be done by selecting the file and pressing F7 but I'm always double clicking accidentally and visual studio takes forever to open the design view page (even if its almost empty), but I just wanna go straight to the code.

Any tips?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had this problem too.  My solution was to change Visual Studio to open up pages in HTML view by default.  Because VS doesn't need to format the page, this is MUCH quicker.  You can see how to get Visual Studio to open pages in HTML view at http://www.wiseowl.co.uk/blog/s153/visual-studio-html-view.htm.

> To tell Visual Studio 2010 to open files automatically in Source view,
>
> - `Tools -> Options`
> - Select the `General` section of the `HTML Designer` tab.
> - Choose to `start pages in Source View`.

Comment: Andy, can you summarize the link, in case it dies of bit-rot?

Comment: What is bit-rot?!  It won't die, rest assured (not before I do, anyway ...).

Comment: Even MSDN changes their link structure, lots of links on SO end up going nowhere after a couple of years... and, what if you get hit by a bus tomorrow? :-P

Comment: I take your point, but I'll risk it.  The whole point of blogging is to avoid having to reproduce the same thing over and over again.  Sorry!

Comment: The whole point of answers on this site is for them to be self-contained. Links with no real details aren't helpful in the long-term.

Answer (score 4):

Just incase Andy's link dies, the method to make Visual Studio open ASPX pages in HTML view rather than the default designer view:

Go to Tools -> Options. Select HTML Designer from the menu at left. Select "HTML View" for HTML pages, Active Server Pages and Web Form pages. Click OK.

This forces VS to open pages in HTML view, which for developers is usually the view we work in for editing ASPX templates. In addition, it addresses the original issue of this question, which is getting VS to open pages faster, since it doesn't have to render a designer view.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are asking to configure VS2010 to take you to the .cs / .vb file when you double click on the aspx page, but you could also be asking about make it go to the html source view.

If you are wondering about the latter (html source view), here is a screenshot of what setting to change.

http://screencast.com/t/8UluCEUQr

I hope this helps.

Comment: yeah I mean taking me to the code-behind file, the actual .cs/vb file, not the html.. and that screen seems to show how to change that :) thanks!